# How to introduce multi-column constraint with JPA annotations?

Tags: java, jpa, mapping

I am trying to introduce a multi-key constraint on a JPA-mapped entity:

```
public class InventoryItem {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Version 
    private Long version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("productId")
    private Product product;

    @Column(nullable=false);
    private long serial;
}
```

Basically (product, serial) pair should be unique, but I only found a way to say that serial should be unique.  This obviously isn't a good idea since different products might have same serial numbers.

Is there a way to generate this constraint via JPA or am I forced to manually create it to DB?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You can declare unique constraints using the `@Table(uniqueConstraints = ...)` annotation in your entity class, i.e.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"productId", "serial"})
}) 
public class InventoryItem {
    ...
}
```

Note that this does not magically create the unique constraint in the database, you still need  a DDL for it to be created. But seems like you are using some sort of automated tool for creating the database based on JPA entity definitions.

Comment: Is this sort of thing needed for an existing database with constraints already in place?

Comment: I do believe that the constraint will be created the JPA provider is creating the data base.

Comment: The uniqueness is for (productId) column & (serial) column or for constraint of 2 column in total (productId, serial)?

Comment: How do you add this to validation as well.

Answer (score 95):

As already answered, multi-column index can be added using `@Table` annotation. However, `columnNames` needs to be the name of actual DB columns, not the class attribute. So, if the column is like the following:

```
@Column(name="product_id")
Long productId;
```

Then the `@Table` annotation should be like the following

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints=
       @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"product_id", "serial"}))
```

Comment: This is a very important clarification: table names and not object names.

Comment: The uniqueness is for (productId) column & (serial) column or for constraint of 2 column in total (productId, serial)?

Comment: Kotlin: Take a look on this answer to find an example for kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47000044/285431

Comment: Syntax Error.  You're missing the closing parenthesis on the @Table annotation.