# Multiple unique constraints

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to add some annotation in order to create a unique constraint in one on my entities. I have a entity A where I have two foreign keys to B and C, from A to B and C the relationship is ManyToOne. I want to create a unique constraint in A for B and C. In here and google I could just found example about how to create unique constraint for A and B or A and C.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You want a unique constraint on `B` and another on `C`, or a single one on `B+C`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a composite Unique constraints on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245935/creating-a-composite-unique-constraints-on-multiple-columns)