# Putting unique constraint on multiple fields

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

Let's say I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
public Foo {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String type;

    ...
}
```

Is there a way to express that name and type should be unique together?
Meaning that for example you could have name "x" with type "y" and name "x" with type "z", but not an other "x" with type "y".

@EmbeddedId doesn't do the trick since name can be changed later - type however remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the entity.

Comment: You need to look into constraints. [This should answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772470/how-to-introduce-multi-column-constraint-with-jpa-annotations).

Comment: essentially making them unique together

Comment: With `@UniqueConstraint`, yes.

Comment: ok,that's the answer - sadly I cannot accept a comment, so make it an answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer below with a reference you might want to look at for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Constraints for your Entity on the `@Table` annotation. In your case, you want to make two joined fields unique. You would use the `@UniqueConstraint` annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=
           @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name", "type"}) 
public Foo {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column    
    private String type;

    ...
}
```

[Take a look at the javadoc for `@UniqueConstraint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html).