# kotlin: some problems with arrays in annotations

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, jpa-2.0, kotlin

I have a some problem in annotations:

```
Entity Table(uniqueConstraints = array(UniqueConstraint(columnNames = array("key", "userid")))) 
public class ...
```

In this case I get the following error:

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: found:
>   kotlin.Array required: kotlin.String

There is no problems with **uniqueConstraints = array(...)** but Idea shows me error in **columnNames = array(...)**

I using **hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar**

---

**Workaround**: Instead uniqueConstraints I using composite key (@javax.persistence.IdClass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [spread operator](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

```
UniqueConstraint(columnNames = *array("key", "userid"))
```

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = arrayOf(
        UniqueConstraint(columnNames = arrayOf("key", "key"))
))
```

Also for new version kotlin you may do that:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = [
    UniqueConstraint(columnNames = ["key", "key"])
])
```

Comment: It was 3 years ago. Kotlin was in Milestone and sometimes new version broke existing code
@Alykoff Gali, Regarding latest version, yes, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this myself today. The following snippet works with the most recent version of Kotlin:

```
@ApiResponses(value = *arrayOf(
        ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Unauthorized"),
        ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Item not found")))
```

or a shorter option:

```
@ApiResponses(
    ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Unauthorized"),
    ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "No active snapshots"))
```

if an annotation with an array is defined as:

```
public @interface ApiResponses {
    ApiResponse[] value();
}
```