# Can I use unique combination field in Spring Data ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a spring data elastic search document as follows :

```
@Document(indexName = "outlet")
public class OutletIndex implements IESMapper{

    @Id
    private String name;
    private Long outletId;
    private OutletType type;
    private String address;
    private String geoLocation;
    private String city;

    // getter and setter methods

}
```

Can I make the combination of `city` and `name` field unique? In spring data jpa we can use `@UniqueConstraint` option([How to introduce multi-column constraint with JPA annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772470/how-to-introduce-multi-column-constraint-with-jpa-annotations)). Is there any way to implement it in Spring data ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of unicity in Elasticsearch except the `_uid` field, which is a concatenation of the mapping type and the document `_id`, e.g. `outlet#someName`

Instead of using the `name` as the document `@Id`, you could create another field called `cityName` which would be the concatenation of the `city` and the `name` fields. This alone guarantees that no two documents will have the same `city` and `name` field values, i.e. some kind of lightweight unicity constraint.

In addition, if you want the indexing operation to fail if a second document with the same name/city is indexed, then, when creating new documents, instead of hitting the usual index API with `PUT index/type/someNameSomeCity` you'd hit the [`_create` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#operation-type) like this

```
`PUT index/type/123/someNameSomeCity/_create`
or
`PUT index/type/123/someNameSomeCity?op_type=create`
```

The effect will be that if a document with the same `someNameSomeCity` ID already exists, then the indexing operation will fail, which also implicitly guarantees some sort of unicity.