# Unique Key Constraint in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

How to make a field unique in pojo using spring data jpa?I know how to do that using jpa

For reference: [multi column constraint with jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772470/how-to-introduce-multi-column-constraint-with-jpa-annotations)

If there is a way, is it possible to use with spring boot?

Answer (score 15):

Use the `@UniqueConstraint` annotation to specify that a unique constraint is to be included in the generated DDL for a primary or secondary table.

Alternately, to ensure a field value is unique you can write

```
@Column(unique=true)
String myField;
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the package of `UniqueConstraint`?

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Data JPA you are using JPA, so you specify the unique constraint using JPA. Nothing special from Spring Boot or Spring Data on that front.

Comment: So you are saying we need to use jpa only to make it as unique constraint.Nothing in the spring data jpa

Comment: is this corect?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single column in the table that has `UNIQUE KEY` constraint then you can simply add the attribute `unique=true` in the annotation `@Column`

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
@Column(name = "unique_key_field", nullable = false, unique = true)
String uniqueKeyFied;
```

In case if you have multiple Unique key constraints in the table then you have to simply follow with the `JPA annotations` as the `spring-boot-data-starter` does not provide any special annotations for the table constraints(KEY/UNIQUEKEY).

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name", uniqueConstraints={
          @UniqueConstraint( name = "idx_col1_col2",  columnNames ={"col1","col2"})
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo em Kotlin:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_XXX",
    uniqueConstraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(name = "sessionid_uindex", columnNames = ["sessionId"])
    ]
)
data class XxxReturn(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "XXX_ID")
    var id: Long? = null,

    var sessionId: String,

    var msg: String
)
```