# Mysql Unique constraint over multiple columns

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have this table and, as the code shows, I have marked columns "***cnpj, product, proposalNumber***" as a unique composed constraint:

```
    @Table(name = "Proposal", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"cnpj", "product", "proposalNumber"})})
    public class Proposal {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, insertable = false)
        @JsonProperty("id")
        private Long id;
    
        @JsonProperty("cnpj")
        @Column(name = "cnpj", nullable = false, length = 14)
        private String cnpj;
    
        @JsonProperty("proposalNumber")
        @Column(name = "proposalNumber", nullable = false)
        private String proposalNumber;
    
        @JsonProperty("product")
        @Column(name = "product", nullable = false, length = 100)
        private String product;
    
        @JsonProperty("price")
        @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
        private BigDecimal price;
    
        @JsonProperty("dueDate")
        @Column(name = "dueDate", nullable = false)
        private String dueDate;
    
        @JsonProperty("qtyLife")
        @Column(name = "qtyLife", nullable = false)
        private Integer qtyLife;
    
        @JsonIgnore
        @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
        private Boolean active = true;

        ...
```

But, checking the DDL or DUMP ain't no unique information...

```
CREATE TABLE `proposal` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `due_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `proposal_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `qty_life` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

In addition to this, writing `@Column(unique = true)` on the column does not solve the problem either, it creates the unique constraint in the database but **only** referencing that single column, not the composition (***cnpj, product and proposalNumber***).

Any tips?

Comment: Why don't you generate the DDL yourself? In production environments that's often the preferred way so that errors in the mapping can't mess up your database.

Comment: I believe this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772470/how-to-introduce-multi-column-constraint-with-jpa-annotations

Comment: @Thomas, at this point I am just the guy who must have it done this way, unfortunatelly not the one who gives the rules haha

Comment: @Folkem I think that is just what I did, but checking de DDL it does not have the composed unique constraint and if "this does not magically create the unique constraint in the database, you still need a DDL for it to be created" what is the purpose of declaring uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint ... ? I am confused right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved: nothing wrong with my solution, but I had to change my `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`